# Modern HTTP-Requests for login/register system

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, ecmascript-6, xml, http

I am working on a login/register system and want the register and log in process as smooth as possible. One way of making it smoother is in my opinion to make a multi-step login/register.

What I mean: If a user want's to log in, he first have to type in his username and if this username exists, he can type in a password and log in. The user has more feedback, especially in the register process. Since I started to learn OOP and know that es6 was introduces a while ago, I want to improve in JS aswell.

I only have one button that does everything. That's why I have a switch case in my button event listener that compares the value of it to select the right method in my form class.

The code at the bottom is what I have came up with. It works but I don't think it is how it's done normally.

Is this code 'advanced' or does it look like it's from a noob.

I am aware that doing a login like that leaks information, but I have already setup a robust protection against it. So that attackers don't have a lot of tries, while users can login wihtout a DoS.

```
class Form {
    content = document.getElementById('content');
    username = document.getElementById('username');
    password = document.getElementById('password');
    submit_btn = document.getElementById('right');
    loader = document.getElementById('loader');
    request;

    constructor () {
        this.request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    execute(type, path, Data) {
        this.loading();
        this.request.open(type, path);
        this.request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        this.request.send(Data);
    }

    loading() {
        this.loader.style.opacity = 1;
    }

    loaded() {
        this.loader.style.opacity = 0;
    }

    submit_username () {
        this.request.onload = () => {
            this.loaded();

            //If response value is true than
            //Switch Input field to password
            //Change button value to login_two
            //else show error messages

        }

        let Data = `username=${this.username.value}`

        this.execute('post', '/login/step_one', Data);
    }

    submit_login() {
        this.request.onload = () => {
            this.loaded();

            //If response value is true than
            //Redirect the user to home
            //else show error messages

        }

        let Data = `password=${this.password.value}`

        this.execute('post', '/login/step_two', Data);

    }

}

const form = new Form();

form.submit_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let method = form.submit_btn.value;
    switch (method) {
        case 'login_one':
            form.submit_username();
        break;
        case 'login_two':
            form.submit_login();
        break;
    }
});
```

Maybe someone can provide an example of a better way.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Mointy/pen/zYYRzYY)

Answer (score 1):

- Declaring a class makes sense if it can be reused, but less so if the logic and element ids are hardcoded to just one case, it only adds the unnecessary `this.` to variables.
- It's unclear why the click listener is handled outside of the form class as it's logically and conceptually a part of the form.
- JS naming convention is camelCase, not snake_case.
- Consider [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) API so the HTTP headers are set [automatically](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-bodyinit-extract) and values are properly escaped.
- Consider making the login routes more declarative e.g. `routes` in the code below.
- If your goal was to use a class as a namespace then it might be better to switch to modules. For example using the built-in ES modules the inner contents of the function will be the entire contents of the module.

```js
function handleLogin() {
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const loader = document.getElementById('loader');
  const btn = document.getElementById('right');
  let step = 0;
  const routes = [{
    path: 'one',
    field: 'username',
    onload() {
      step++;
      getDataElement().focus();
    },
    onerror(e) { /* show error */ },
  }, {
    path: 'two',
    field: 'password',
    onload() { /* show home page */ },
    onerror(e) { /* show error */ },
  }];

  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    loader.style.opacity = 1;
    const {path, field} = routes[step];
    request.open('post', `/login/step_${path}`);
    request.send(new URLSearchParams({[field]: getDataElement().value}));
  });

  request.addEventListener('loadend', e => {
    loader.style.opacity = 0;
    routes[step][request.response === 'true' ? 'onload' : 'onerror'](e);
  });

  function getDataElement() {
    return document.getElementById(routes[step].field);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! No, my goal was not to use the class as a namcespace. I just wanted my code to be more modern and scaleable. Since I dont need module I dont need it as function. However I am trying to expand it, because the registering process works the same way as the login.

Comment: Well without seeing the full workflow I don't see what can be scaled here as it's too simple. Like I already said, with the info present so far I see no benefits in using a class here, quite the opposite.

Comment: I added a codepen link where you will see what I mean. The code you posted is fine, I dont need to have everything in a function (handleLogin), since it should execute when the file loads.  But I also want the same functionality for registering a user without the need of copying everything.

Comment: FWIW you can call a function just fine or you can make it an IIFE `(() => {...})()` As for copying, there's not much to copy so I'm against adding superficial complexity of classes and inheritance.